# Python Regex - getting file name

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble with the following

I need to use a regex to get the file name, after a 'Name: '

> Name: somefile.something.0001.bla
>
> Name: somestuff.0212.somethat.hah

I need everything but 'Name: '

Comment: Does the entire input string consist of "Name: " followed by the name, or can the expression "Name: <filename>" appear anywhere in the string?  And how many times can it appear?  Once?  Many times?  Answers to your question depend on the context.  If you can be more precise that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you're sure that it is always `"Name: "` that you want to remove, you can do

```
my_string[6:]
```

Comment: thanks, that will work but I can only use a regex as a solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for that... But, if you really want:

```
re.sub(r'^Name: ', '', string)
```

Or something more useful to remove extra spaces

```
re.sub(r'^Name:\s+', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more than one way to do it, but this will work:

```
re.search("(Name: )(.+)","Name: somefile.something.0001.bla").groups()[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
index = mystring.find("Name:")
newstring = mystring[:index]+mystring[index+5:]
```